# Проблемы при получение доступа к AppCenter distribute

Tags: c#

Не так давно решил поиграться с Microsoft решениями для разработчиков, настроил так, что каждый Commit отправленный в DevOps автоматически начинается собираться, проверяться и релизиться на платформе AppCenter, а от туда по средствам их API я получаю информацию про релиз (описание, версию, размер, md5 и так далее), вроде все хорошо, НО!

Небольшая группа пользователей моего приложения начали жаловаться на то, что проект невозможно обновить, пособирав информацию я выяснил, что у них CDN Microsoft разрывает соединение, и приложение выдает:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.

Я начал разбираться, в чем же дело и выяснил, что сервера Microsoft требуют Tls1.2, хорошо, я добавил следующее:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

И многим это помогло, приложение успешно получает данные и обновляется, но увы, не всем. Пошел спрашивать людей, попытался воспроизвести это дело и на данный момент имею следующее:

- Почти у  всех людей, кто сталкивается с данной проблемой стоит Windows 7.
- Сервера Microsoft то включают, то выключаю поддержку протоколов, отличающихся от Tls1.2.

Я сделал небольшой тест, который в цикле перебирает `SecurityProtocolType` и на каждое значение отправляет запрос на сервер (чисто получение заголовков) и записывает этот результат в коллекцию, делаю это N раз с задержкой между "тестами" 5сек и получил следующую картину:

Мой тест (15 прогонов):

> SystemDefault: Successfully: 15 | Fault: 0
> Ssl3: Successfully: 0 | Fault: 15
> Tls: Successfully: 0 | Fault: 15
> Tls11: Successfully: 2 | Fault: 13
> Tls12: Successfully: 15 | Fault: 0
> Tls13: Successfully: 0 | Fault: 15

Результат одного из, у которых проблема с доступом (15 прогонов):

> SystemDefault: Successfully: 2 | Fault: 13
> Ssl3: Successfully: 0 | Fault: 15
> Tls: Successfully: 4 | Fault: 11
> Tls11: Successfully: 2 | Fault: 13
> Tls12: Successfully: 2 | Fault: 13
> Tls13: Successfully: 0 | Fault: 15

То есть у человека как такового доступа нет, его попросту сервер Microsoft блокирует.

Дальше я решил узнать, а что все же Microsoft поддерживает, какой мне использовать протокол, нашел в интернете несколько тестов и вижу это:

[image: TlsTest1]

Вроде все нормально, поддерживает все необходимое, лезу на другой ресурс, делают замер и вижу это:

[image: TlsTest2]

Думаю, ну может сбоит тест, пойду еще найду проверку, нашел, сделал и получил:

[image: TlsTest3]

То есть сервера Microsoft то дают доступ то нет и это для меня не очень понятно...

Я сделал тестовый проект, может вы поможете разобраться в чем дело?

API на последнюю версию: `https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/public/sdk/apps/8384d16d-0e59-4067-bb88-1d53c335f286/releases/latest`
Ссылка на CDN, который должен дать файл и который частично не пускает находится в API, значение `download_url`.

А да, самое мистичное для меня тут то, что при открытие данной ссылки обычным браузером, он успешно скачивается, **всегда**. Это натолкнуло меня на мысль, что проблема в заголовках (хотя какие заголовки у API), дал UserAgent, другие заголовки и что-то это не особо дало результата. Отловил запрос с браузера, тот без особых заголовков отправляет запрос с использованием SSL3, задал его в программе, результата нет, задал `SSL3 | Tls12` и тоже нет результата.

Короче, кто знает, в чем проблема, что не так с этим CDN? Почему он небольшое кол-во людей блокирует?

---

Запустил вон сейчас по ссылке выше свой тест, получил это:

```
Test №1
 > SystemDefault - OK
 > Ssl3 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы
 > Tls - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 > Tls11 - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 > Tls12 - OK
 > Tls13 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы

Test №2
 > SystemDefault - OK
 > Ssl3 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы
 > Tls - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 > Tls11 - OK
 > Tls12 - OK
 > Tls13 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы

Test №3
 > SystemDefault - OK
 > Ssl3 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы
 > Tls - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 > Tls11 - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 > Tls12 - OK
 > Tls13 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы
```

Каждый "тест" идет как я уже говорил после 5-ти секундной задержки и видно, что сначала запрос через Tls11 был заблокирован, через 5 секунд он прошел, а еще через 5 он опять был заблокирован. Если чуть подождать, то можно такое наблюдать и с другими протоколами, например:

```
Test №9
 > SystemDefault - OK
 > Ssl3 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы
 > Tls - OK
 > Tls11 - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
 > Tls12 - OK
 > Tls13 - Взаимодействие клиента и сервера невозможно, т.к. у них разный алгоритм работы
```

Tls вдруг получил ответ. И это у меня так, у человека, который всегда имеет доступ к этим ссылкам, а у людей бывает что и Tls1.2 заблокирован, Как? Почему? Может есть какие либо параметры, которые помогут это решить? И почему тогда **через простой браузер идет всегда запрос**? Чего я упускаю?

---

В тех. поддержку написал, но от них ответа несколько лет надо ждать, раз в день по сообщению шлют, а сейчас из за выходных так тем более на несколько дней пропадут, а люди страдают...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
> ```

Так делать **нельзя**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

> Do not specify the TLS version. Configure your code to let the OS decide on the TLS version.

В коде вообще никаких установок свойства ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol не должно быть. Если что-то не работает, это нужно решать настройками реестра / обновлениями ОС, а не привязкой к конкретному протоколу на уровне кода.

> Почти у всех людей, кто сталкивается с данной проблемой стоит Windows 7.

В этом нет ничего удивительного. Вы зашили в коде использование TLS 1.2. .NET Framework при работе с криптографией использует [SChannel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-), стандартный компонент Windows. В Windows 7 в SChannel TLS 1.2 по умолчанию отключен (см. таблицу по ссылке). Решается эта проблема включением его через реестр: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#tls-12

> Короче, кто знает, в чем проблема, что не так с этим CDN? Почему он небольшое кол-во людей блокирует?

На этот вопрос могут ответить только администраторы CDN

> И почему тогда через простой браузер идет всегда запрос?

Если "простой браузер" на движке Chrome, то он использует не SChannel, а OpenSSL, совершенно другую реализацию, и по протоколам и по наборам шифров. Соответственно, от версии Windows уже ничего не будет зависеть, но будет зависеть от версии OpenSSL в браузере. Короче, это вещи не сравнимые.

---

То есть в итоге вам нужно сделать следующее:

- Выпилить из кода все конструкции типа ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ...
- Рекомендовать клиентам включить у себя в настройках SChannel новые протоколы (TLS 1.2 и TLS 1.3 в случае достаточно новой версии Windows 10). Реализовать программную установку, если потребуется.

Поддержку более старых протоколов будут отрубать, и это хорошо. TLS 1.0/1.1 довольно старый и в нем есть уязвимости. Если нет необходимости поддержки WinXP/2003, он и не нужен. Вероятно у вас сейчас CDN балансирует нагрузку между разными серверами, каждый из которых поддерживает разный набор протоколов, отсюда и аномалии. Но на старые протоколы так или иначе не нужно полагаться.

Comment: Если не задавать протокол явно, то в некоторых случаях идут ошибки по типу `System.Net.WebException: Запрос был прерван: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS.`, ну либо опять "Сервер принудительно разорвал соединение". Не у всех и не всегда, но без этой строки многие жаловались, пришлось добавить и теперь только единицы ругаются на то, что у них не работает обновление. Кстати, сейчас с человеком сидел и просматривал его реестр, все значения по включению TLS 1.2 в порядке. Вот вам аномалия...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "Сервер принудительно разорвал соединение" - эта ошибка прямого отношения к криптографии не имеет, просто сервер не справляется с нагрузкой. А какая целевая версия .NET Framework у вашего приложения?

Comment: Microsoft меня вчера послали благополучно на 3 веселые буквы, сказав, что проблема не в серверах и не в AppCenter. Посоветовали написать в поддержку самой Windows... Framework используется версии 4.7.2.

Comment: А по поводу нагрузки - я тоже об этом думал, но эта теория разбивается о несколько фактов: 1. У человека нет постоянно доступа, даже если мы будем "долбить сервер до посинения с небольшой задержкой и ждать успешного соединения". 2. Тогда такая проблема была бы у всех, а не у единиц.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Microsoft другого и не скажет, Win7 же больше не поддерживается, так что они не обязаны под нее подстраиваться. В поддержку Windows писать бесполезно по той же причине. CDN балансирует нагрузку между серверами в том числе и на основе географического положения, так что вполне объяснимо, что у кого-то работает, а у кого-то нет. У меня вот на машине с Win7 все нормально работает, 10 из 10 тестов успешно и при SystemDefault, и при явно заданном TLS 1.2. А на проблемной машине Windows обновляется? В частности, [KB3140245](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245.) установлено?

Comment: Мы проверили поддержку TLS 1.2, даже при помощи [сторонних](https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check) ресурсов, она есть, все работает как надо. Но не качает. Знакомый, с которым мы делаем проект не особо знающий C#, но разбирающийся в паскаль, написал свой тест, который использует `WebClient` и пытается загрузить файл (не как я получение заголовков, а полная загрузка файла), несколько проходов - 1. без установки TLS, второй с принудительным TLS 1.2. У многих без принудительной установки соединения нет и что самое интересное, на `WebClient` заработала загрузка у людей с Win7 кривой.

Comment: Я сегодня попробовал на виртуалку накатить самую кривейшую и обрезанную Win7, запустил там тест - дал TLS 1.0 поддержку, все красное, все плохо, запускаю обновление - сервера успешно отдали файл, программа обновилась. Хотя тесты скажем так, [не утешительные](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/570676015815327774/726814074758889593/unknown.png).