# Как в .NET5 задать TLS13 программно

Tags: c#, https, httpclient, tls

У провайдера есть сервер с какой-то старой версией Windows (возможно, что даже не Windows Server 2012, а Windows Server 2008) c IIS10 - и у меня был запущен там сайт с ботом телеграм. Изначально он не заработал, т.к. у telegram обязательно требуется https и не ниже чем TLS1.2 - но когда я попросил доставить нужные kb'шки - доставили и недели три работало нормально, а потом снова отвалилось и снова по-причине неработающего TLS.

И вот тут я взялся отлаживать прямо на низком уровне - ведь [бот телеграм](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) использует [тот же](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/4/proxy.html#http-proxy) самый `HttpClient`.

И я взял для образца [сайт](https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check), который отдаёт список установленных шифров и сделал минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```cs
protected static async Task<string> TestTls()
{
    //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var uri = "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return result;
}
```

И этот код не заработал, выдав ошибку `Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.`

Trace:

```
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at WebApp1.Controllers.TestController.TestTls() in C:\proj\test\src\WebApp1\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 83
at WebApp1.Controllers.TestController.Update(Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\proj\test\src\WebApp1\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 28 
Exception: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
ExceptionInner: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
ExceptionInnerInner: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
```

При этом техподдержка мастерхоста говорит, что хоть и сервер старый - но они всё настроили и у них всё работает.
Приводят скрипт powershell в котором они тыкали реальный адрес https (и я видел в своём чате телеграм сообщение HelloWorld, поэтому верю)

`$InitialSecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 Invoke-WebRequest "https://api.telegram.org/bot<MySecretKeyHere>/sendMessage?chat_id=<RealChatIdHere>&text=HelloWorld" -UseBasicParsing`

Т.е. задача сводится к тому, чтобы из кода C# включить Tls12 или Tls13

И вот как это сделать - вопрос. В документации майкрософт [написано](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) "если у вас фреймворк выше 4.7 - то пусть ОС сама делает выбор протоколов", в более ранних версиях рекомендуется ставить

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

При этом у меня не работает никак, хоть у меня .NET 5 (CORE, не Framework). Если попробовать проанализировать при помощи https://www.ssllabs.com контроллер - то видно, что сервер поддерживает TLS 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0 и не поддерживает SSL 3 и 2 - и общая оценка в тесте весьма высокая (grade "B").

И как это тогда делается правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно дополнительное исследование, давайте порефлексируем немного, написал тестовый HTTP запрос.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new(); // { DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20 };

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using var response = await client.GetAsync("https://google.com/", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    Console.WriteLine($"HTTP/{response.Version}");
    var contentStream = GetPrivateField(response.Content, "_stream");
    if (response.Version == HttpVersion.Version20)
    {
        contentStream = GetPrivateField(contentStream, "_http2Stream");
    }
    var connection = GetPrivateField(contentStream, "_connection");
    SslStream sslStream = (SslStream)GetPrivateField(connection, "_stream");
    Console.WriteLine(sslStream.SslProtocol);
    Console.WriteLine(sslStream.NegotiatedCipherSuite);
}

private static object GetPrivateField(object obj, string field) 
    => obj.GetType().GetField(field, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(obj);
```

.NET 6, Windows 11, проверяю обе версии HTTP, получаю:

```
HTTP/1.1
Tls13
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

```
HTTP/2.0
Tls13
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Рекомендую протестировать, это поможет разобраться. Если вы получите TLS 1.3 на гугле, а к себе не сможете подключиться, или получите 1.2, значит проблема на стороне сервера. Если на гугле получите 1.2, значит проблема на стороне клиента.

---

При всём при этом, ваш метод `TestTls()` выдает то же самое исключение. С причинами я не разобрался, надо снифать трафик, сравнивать что шлет браузер и что шлет .NET, а у меня сейчас нет времени для глубоких раскопок.

---

Как задать настройки TLS версии для `HttpClient` в .NET Core 3+ явно:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new(new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    SslOptions = new() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13 | SslProtocols.Tls12 }
});
```

Comment: И на https 1 и 2 получаю одинаковую ошибку на гугле: `Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'DecodeError'.ExceptionInnerInner: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.` Причём падает сразу на `await client.GetAsync` ничего не успев вывести в консоль.

Comment: @AK это указывает на отсутствие поддержки TLS1.3 или шифрсьютов для него со стороны ОС, при чем однозначно. .NET 6 пробуешь? хотя разницы быть не должно, но я б рекомендовал тестить именно на 6-м.

Comment: Пробую .NET 5 шестой нету. Но странно, что ssllabs  [видит](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.mafiasyndicate.ru&hideResults=on) установленный TLS1.3 и что скрипты powershell видят tls1.3 - а из-под IIS код не видит. Поэтому и вопрос, как его выбирать, если он как бы есть.

Comment: @AK а как у тебя гугел падает, что-то я не пойму, он по-любому должен приконнектиться, если не с 1.3, то с 1.2 точно. _И на https 1 и 2 получаю одинаковую ошибку на гугле:_ - это значит что у тебя TLS1.2 тоже не поддерживается, как бы удивительно это не казалось. Или вообще что-то сломано в винде.

Comment: Попробовал указанный сайт, последовательно 6 тестов: три на https2.0 и три на дефолтном (вероятно, это будет 1.1, но не уверен). Три теста: ничего не указываю в ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol потом указываю ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13; и затем tls12 - во всех случаях ошибка одна и та же: Exception: `The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.` ExceptionInner: `Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'IllegalParameter'.` ExceptionInnerInner: `The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.`

Comment: @AK `ServicePointManager` на .NET 5 ничего не делает, совсем ничего, он только на 4.x фреймворке работает. Управление характеристиками соединений на .NET Core 3+ выполняется через параметры `SocketsHttpHandler`. А `ServicePointManager` управляет настройками `WebRequestHandler`, который в .NET Core не используется.

Comment: @AK дополнил ответ

Comment: Блистательно! Именно этого я оказывается и не знал. На TLS1.3 не работает, но HTTP/1.1 + Tls12 + 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 сконнектилось. Если бы я знал это раньше, я бы не потратил неделю на раскопки, а сразу бы пришёл к правильному результату. Это галка, плюс досыплю сверху.

Comment: @AK очень странно, что без явного указания не работает, должно. С большой вероятностью, у вас что-то не так с операционной системой, это в любом случае стоит порешать.

Comment: Очередное возрождение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140565/ , только на этот раз с .NET 5? И вновь возникает классический вопрос, а нужно ли прописывать эти версии протокола в коде? Может TLS1.2 просто в реестре выставлен DisabledByDefault, и его включение решит проблему?

Comment: @AK проверь реестр по предыдущему комменту.